# Android Registration form not posting to MySQL - localhost

Tags: php, android, registration

I am new to android and trying to learn develop a simple registration form.  I followed an [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lHBfyQgkiAA#t=19.415423436) tutorial and the codes for the same are available in [github](https://github.com/tonikami/NEWLoginRegister/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/tonikamitv/loginregister).
I am using php-mysql installed locally on my machine.  Hence for the path to url - both register request as well as login request, I am using the following urls:

```
http://192.168.0.101/register.php
http://192.168.0.101/login.php
```

When I run these files in my browser locally using:

```
http://127.0.0.1/register.php
http://127.0.0.1/login.php
```

it doesn't return any error.

The connection in the register and login php files are made as follows:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "ABCABC", "agnya");
```

The app upon providing username and password should open a third page or when I register using the registration page, should update the db and return the login page.

The problem is:

The app runs on VM locally without any errors, however upon entering the details and clicking the login or register buttons, I see no action or no error messages.  I have tried changing the url in various combinations as follows:

```
127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1:3306, 192.168.0.101,192.168.0.101:3306, localhost, 10.0.2.2, 10.0.2.3
```

and in the php files instead of localhost i have used all these and in various combinations of these.

I have been struggling with a solution for this for the last 3 days, but to no avail.  Do i have to use a `jsonparser`- I saw an option like that somewhere.

I configured a table in Mysql hosted on the cloud, and used the cloud credentials, still not working.  Any thoughts?

Application Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="INTERNET"></uses-permission>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".registerActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".userDetailsActivity"></activity>
</application>
```

RegisterActivity.java

```
   package inagnya.axiomanalytics.www.agnya;


import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.content.Intent;

import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class registerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        final EditText etNameReg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNameReg);
        final EditText etUsernameReg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsernameLog);
        final EditText etPasswordReg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPasswordLog);
        final EditText etAgeReg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAgeWel);
        final Button btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);


        btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final String name = etNameReg.getText().toString();
                final String username = etUsernameReg.getText().toString();
                final String password = etPasswordReg.getText().toString();
                final int age = Integer.parseInt(etAgeReg.getText().toString());

                Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                            boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                            if (success) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(registerActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                                registerActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                            } else {
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(registerActivity.this);
                                builder.setMessage("Registration Failed")
                                        .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                        .create()
                                        .show();

                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                };

                RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest(name,username,password,age,responseListener);
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(registerActivity.this);
                queue.add(registerRequest);
            }
        });

    }


    }
```

RegisterRequest.java

```
package inagnya.axiomanalytics.www.agnya;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

/**
 * Created by mageshpoondi on 08/01/17.
 */

public class RegisterRequest extends StringRequest{

    private static final String REGISTER_REQUEST_URL = "http://192.168.0.101/register.php";
    private Map<String, String> params;

    public RegisterRequest(String name, String username, String password, int age, Response.Listener<String> listener) {
        super(Method.POST, REGISTER_REQUEST_URL,listener,null);
        params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("name", name);
        params.put("username", username);
        params.put("password", password);
        params.put("age", age + "");
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getParams() {
        return params;
    }
    }
```

activity_register.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_register"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="inagnya.axiomanalytics.www.agnya.registerActivity">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="11dp"
        android:id="@+id/etNameReg"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:hint="Name" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etNameReg"
        android:id="@+id/etUsernameLog"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/etNameReg"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/etNameReg"
        android:hint="Username" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/etPasswordLog"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etUsernameLog"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/etUsernameLog"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/etUsernameLog"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:hint="Password" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etPasswordLog"
        android:id="@+id/etAgeWel"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/etPasswordLog"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/etPasswordLog"
        android:hint="Age" />

    <Button
        android:text="Register"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etAgeWel"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/etAgeWel"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/etAgeWel"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
        android:id="@+id/btnRegister"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

ifconfig output

```
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether a4:5e:60:c1:9d:6b 
    inet6 fe80::a65e:60ff:fec1:9d6b%en0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x4 
    inet 192.168.0.101 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.0.255
    nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
```

Comment: Still not getting your question?? Like what do  you want and whats that happening and should not happen ???

Comment: When I try to register, the registration details are not updated in MySql....so is when I try to login...I am not able to login....but the VM is not returning any error.

Comment: do u know your ip address of PC ? and the local server that u using are u putting all files correctly ?

Comment: Yes...I used ifconfig to fetch my IP...the IP given in the query is the right ip...But when I the ip 127.0.0.1 in my browser the php file runs, however, not the 192.168.0.101.  Though the android app doesn't return anything either case.

Comment: print logs inside your php files using echo to check whether connection is establishing.

Comment: 192.168.0.101 is that your router ip address? then you need to forward your port from router to connect to the pc.

Comment: What response do you get when you send the form? Create a dummy page on your server, for example a Hello World! in php. Do you see this page in your mobile's browser?

Comment: @SadiqMdAsif I am updating my ifconfig output...just to ensure if i am using the correct ip.

Comment: @Apricot follow this link

Answer (score 0):

Certainly Its an example to show how to achieve(It is an example to show and does not contains exact answer asked by user).Try Networking Lib.("Volley") for calls. I example for Login and Registration.

```
//Layout of Activity
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="2dp"
tools:context="com.test.test.ScreenOne">


<EditText
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/etUsername"
    android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
    android:hint="username"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/etPassword"
    android:hint="password"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etUsername"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Login"
    android:id="@+id/bLogin"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etPassword"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Save"
    android:id="@+id/bSave"
    android:layout_below="@+id/bLogin"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="42dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity has 2 buttons and 2 EditText, Login button login via server and Save button saves your data in server:

```
package com.test.test;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class ScreenOne extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String URL_LOGIN = "http://IP_ADDRESS/login.php";
private static final String URL_SAVE = "http://IP_ADDRESS/save.php";
private EditText username;
private EditText password;
private Button login;
Button save;
String name;
String pass;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.screen_one);

    username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);

    (login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLogin)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            request();
        }
    });

    (save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSave)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            saveRequest();
        }
    });
}

private void saveRequest() {
    name = username.getText().toString().trim();
    pass = password.getText().toString().trim();
    final ProgressDialog mDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    mDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    mDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    mDialog.show();

    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_SAVE,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    mDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(ScreenOne.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    username.setText("");
                    password.setText("");
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    mDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(ScreenOne.this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> key = new HashMap<>();
            key.put("username", name);
            key.put("password", pass);
            return key;
        }
    };

    NetworkCalls.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request);
}

private synchronized void request() {
    name = username.getText().toString().trim();
    pass = password.getText().toString().trim();
    final ProgressDialog mDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    mDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    mDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    mDialog.show();

    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_LOGIN,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    mDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(ScreenOne.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    username.setText("");
                    password.setText("");
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    mDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(ScreenOne.this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> key = new HashMap<>();
            key.put("username", name);
            key.put("password", pass);
            return key;
        }
    };

    NetworkCalls.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request);
 }
}
```

Singleton class for Volley request:

```
import android.content.Context;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

/**
 * Created by W4R10CK on 12-09-2016.
 */
public class NetworkCalls {
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private static Context context;

    private static NetworkCalls ourInstance = new NetworkCalls();

    public static NetworkCalls getInstance() {
        return ourInstance;
    }

    private NetworkCalls() {
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue(){
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context.getApplicationContext());
        return requestQueue;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> request){
        getRequestQueue().add(request);
    }
}
```

API to call server:

```
 //conn.php for connection (file one)
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$db_name = "hello";

$con = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$db_name);

if($con -> connect_error){
echo "Connection error";
}   


//save.php(file two)
<?php
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
require_once('conn.php');

$sql = "INSERT INTO user (username, password) VALUES ('$username','$password')";

if($con -> query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "User added";
}
//$con -> close();
?>
?>

//login.php(file three)
<?php
require_once('conn.php');

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

if(mysqli_fetch_array($result) == NULL){
echo "Invalid Cred.";
}else{
echo "Success";
}

$con->close();
?>
```

Lastly create one DB named **hello** and table in localhost **user** with 2 fields **username**, **password**.

Try to learn more on this link [here](https://www.learn2crack.com/2016/04/android-login-registration-php-mysql-server.html)